# How does this graph show solutions to $x^2+1=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I was recently watching a series on YouTube about imaginary numbers, and how they are not as "imaginary" as the name would suggest. The video used the following 3D graph to show solutions to $x^2+1=0$:

[image]

What is this type of graph? How would I go about creating one for any arbitrary function $f$? What is the graph *plotting*, exactly?

Here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T647CGsuOVU) to the video if you are interested.

Comment: Link to the video?

Comment: The graph is the set if all complex numbers that satisfy the given equation ... To create such a graph extend the domain from real to complex

Comment: The graph drawn is of $f(z)=z^2+1$ keeping in mind that $z$ is now complex and so can be visualized as two-dimensional.  The resulting graph if we want to keep track of all inputs and all of their corresponding outputs would need to be $2\times 2=4$-dimensional! (not three).  That is quite difficult to do, so they opted to use the space out of the page towards the ceiling as another dimension and using color as the fourth dimension.  They didn't draw the entire graph, only a relevant portion of it to get the point across, and it doesn't look like they even drew the graph correctly...

Comment: In the end though, you would be able to look at the output dimensions and where in there corresponds to an output of zero, and then look at the input dimensions to see which value(s) led to that as an output, similar to how in the case with our input and output both being one-dimensional we can look to see where the curve crosses the $x$-axis.  Here, we look to see where the surface crosses the $z$-$w$ plane, and on a correctly drawn image this would occur for you exactly at the points $(0,1,0,0)$ and $(0,-1,0,0)$ corresponding to $0+1i$ and $0+(-1)i$ respectively.

Comment: It's a pity you haven't given the url for this video. What I can say is, if this video is for learning what are complex numbers, it is surely done by an amateur teacher that wants not to be understood : do not proceed to work with it [Trust me : I have explained what are and what one can do with complex numbers and complex functions to several people].

Comment: @JeanMarie, link added! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T647CGsuOVU

Comment: @HansLundmark https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T647CGsuOVU

Comment: The muti-colored object appears to be a representation of the real portion of the graph of $f(x+iy) = x^2 - y^2 + 1$

Comment: @Doug M I don't think so because level curve $z=0$ would in this case be a branch of hyperbola, not a parabola.

Comment: @JeanMarie the plane $z = 0$ is that grid rising off the page.  The level curve would be in the blue portion,  And who is to say that that is not a half a hyperbola vs. a parabola.  Can't really tell from the picture.

Comment: @Doug M Seen like this... I just had a look at the video (seen by over a million people...) . It is very talkative but doesn't bring information about this surface. I advise to the OP to see much less bizarre introductions like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f079K1f2WQk (though linked to physics)